# Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS: Playchess.com crashes my system

Tags: webapps

After I play for a while, my system crashes and I have to use the on-off switch.

CPU: AMD FX(tm)-6300 Six-Core Processor

GPU: Cape Verde XT [Radeon HD 7770/8760 / R7 250X]

RAM: 8GiB

Comment: Edit your question, put system cpu ram gpu specifications. may be due to low ram if it is less than 4gb, if your ram is low consider upgrading ram and / or installing lubuntu.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: I have already tested it in Chromium and Brave.

Comment: see if adequate swap memory is available